# Google sheets API limits for SAAS applications

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We want to develop an API integration for Google Sheets in our SAAS platform, we have around 1000 users and each user in our platform will be connecting their own Google Account to the integration.

I see the API limits are 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.

What I'm not 100% clear on is if these limits apply to our platform integration as a whole (all users on our platform) or the limits apply to each connected Google Account?

I'm assuming the API limit applies to each individual connected Google Account in our integration so each user in our platform will have their own individual requests limits?

I want to be sure though because the alternative of having only 100 requests per 100 seconds is not very scalable across 1000 users in our platform.

Any clarification on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way the API limits would work for you is that:

Every user would have a limit of 100 requests per 100 seconds per user, since you are performing these requests on the behalf of the user.

If you application was performing these requests instead, then you would reach the 500 requests per 100 seconds.

Hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! 

Just so I'm clear - In our case users of our platform will connect their Google account but then our platform will be sending the data to the users google sheets.

So therefore does this mean because our platform is performing the requests we would actually fall into your second scenario with an overall limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds?

Or does this still mean we are performing requests on behalf of the user and every user will have an individual limit of 100 requests per 100 seconds?

Sorry for the repetition, just want to be sure.

Comment: Hello @user12167322, yes, in that case you would fall into the 500 requests per 100 seconds limit.